# Excel If, If Then colour cell statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Hi I have the following simple excel spreadsheet:

[image]

I want to colour the cell c1 in red if cell a1 > 0 & cell c1 is < .8?

I have been trying conditional formatting but don't think that it has the required functionality. I have also tried my own function but as I'm new to this I would appreciate some help?

Comment: You can use a formula in Conditional Formatting.  Use this formula: `AND(A1>0,C1<.8)`

Comment: @ScottCraner hi scott I tried the above, please see my edit?

Comment: sorry @ScottCraner I was working on a screenshot before I saw your answer in the comment.

Comment: @TripVoltage Try my answer.  Please note the `=` and the `0.8` are slightly different than what you tried.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: You should accept @Chrismas007 answer, He took the time to do a proper write up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight your C column and use the following:

```
=AND(A1>0, C1<0.8)
```

[image]

Gives Me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use the next formula in a conditional formatting in the c1 cell: **=IF(A1=1,IF(C1<0.8,1,0),0)**